# Error in eqsumW[2, -1] : subscript out of bounds - SolveRsocp

Tags: programming, markowitz

I am working on a research project where the goal is to get the highest possible return with different portfolios at a given risk rate. For this I would like to use the function "SolveRsocp" as I do not want to allow shortselling. Unfortunately, when I run this function, I get the error message "Error in eqsumW[2, -1] : subscript out of bounds". Does someone know how to fix this? Thank you for your attention.

Code: ...

```
library("timeSeries")
library("caTools")
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("fAssets")
library("tmvnsim")

library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(forecast)
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
library(ROI)
library(fPortfolio)
library(Rsocp)

#Create Ticker
tickers <- c( "JNJ", "NESN.SW", "PG", "XOM", "ROG.SW"    
)

#Loads data from Yahoo
portfolioPrices <- NULL
for(ticker in tickers) {
  portfolioPrices <- cbind(portfolioPrices,
                           getSymbols.yahoo(ticker, from='2016-07-08', periodicity = 'daily', auto.assign=FALSE)[,6])
}

#deletes missing values
portfolioPrices <- portfolioPrices[apply(portfolioPrices,1,function(x) all(!is.na(x))),]


portfolioReturns <- na.omit(ROC(portfolioPrices,
                                type = "discrete"))
portfolioReturns <- as.timeSeries(portfolioReturns)
lppData= portfolioReturns


#Determination target portfolio - long only
maxRetSpec=portfolioSpec() 
setTargetRisk(maxRetSpec)=0.1 
setSolver(maxRetSpec)="solveRsocp"
setOptimize(maxRetSpec) <- 'maxReturn'
efficientPortfolio(data=lppData, spec=maxRetSpec, constraints="LongOnly")
```

Comment: Hi Georg. The error has something to do with the internal code of the *solveRsocp* method. It seems there's a open merge request that tries to fix the issue [here](https://github.com/r-forge/rmetrics/pull/1/files). However, this has never been implemented. In general,  the fportfolio package is heavily outdated (or so it seems). Try to use the default solver instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help Pleb! I highly appreciate it, have a great sunday!